# How to make row dynamic in Data Driven Framework

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

I am working on a Data Driven Project where my test data is from an excel sheet. Am able to fetch data from sheet, but I need to pass only the column value but not Row value in step defn method, so that my test case can complete one set of testing with one row and move to next row.

My code:

```
public static int getCellData() throws Exception{
    int rowData=0;
    int NumOfRows=0;
    try{
        NumOfRows = ExcelWSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        for(int i=2;i<NumOfRows;i++){
            rowData = ExcelWSheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();}         
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
     return rowData;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to Getting and setting Excel data, provide the Row and Column number. Example: String cellData = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum).getStringCellValue(); Source: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/

Comment: If trying to get data where the first row of the Excel spreadsheet has column 'Titles' and by referencing the 'Title' instead of the column number have a separate function that loops through the first row and stores HashMap the title as index with column number?

Comment: Thanks for response Dan. If I provide RowNum in my method, then it won't be dynamic for next set of data.

Comment: Please can you provide a couple of lines of the data sheet, and what input you provide and output you expect.